# Problems with pip install after python update on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pip

So my computer's in a complete mess.

I used to have Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 installed.

Because Python 2 was installed first, calling PIP from the command line used Python 2.

I uninstalled Python 2, and then pip failed because it was expecting Python2.7 but couldn't find it. Fair enough. (I should have uninstalled pip before uninstalling Python 2, but hey-ho...)

I figured now was good a time to upgrade to Python 3 to v 3.8, and then run get-pip.py afterwards to reinstall pip.

I installed 3.8 from the website and then found that any attempt to run python or python3 from the command line just sent me to the Windows Store. (AARGH!)

Anyhow, I ended up uninstalling Python 3.8 and reinstalling via the Windows Store, then ran get-pip.py...
...and now when I try to run pip, it's complaining that the Python27 directory isn't there(!)

How can I clean this up? I only need Python 3.8 now, and I'm a bit stuck as I can't currently install any libraries/modules....

Thanks!

Comment: I really really encourage installing Anaconda. Download the installer from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and you're ready to go. It will adjust the PythonPath, install pip, and install the most common packages with one click

Answer (score 1):

If you chose any version that you need from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and executable installer, you should have your path already setup.

If it's not, you need to set it manually. Python is installed in `%localappdata%\Programs\Python\` by default (or someplace else if you changed it on installation).
In Environment Variables(just press window key and type it, hit enter, than select tab Advanced and you should see button with this name) you need to add in User variables, Path (double click) these new entries:

1. `%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\`

2. `%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Python36\`

3. `%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Launcher\`

pip is located in 1. Note that you need to use your version instead of Python36.

Comment: This doesn't affect the problem -- there is no path for python 3.7 in either the user of system environment variables. It turns out that I can run pip with the command "pip3.8" or "python.exe -m pip...", but pip and pip3 both try to run the (now uninstalled) Python 3.7 environment.

So I have a workaround and can install new packages, but the underlying problem is floating around somewhere. Never mind -- I can program in Python again anyway.